# How to add numbers and save each time accumulated value?

Tags: javascript

Image a set of numbers

```
const numbers = [20, 30, 50, 100, 150]
```

The expected outcome ::

```
[20, 50, 100, 200, 350]

// explanation [20, 20 + 50, 20 + 50 + 100, 20 + 50 + 100 + 200, 20 + 50 + 100 + 200 + 350]

// i.e. (sum up to (n-1)th + n th)
```

This is what I've tried:

```
numbers.map((div, inx, array) => (inx === 0 ? 0 : (array[inx - 2] || 0) + array[inx - 1]));
```

also tried:

```
numbers.reduce((acc, cur, inx) => [...acc, cur + acc[inx-1]], []);
```

**The idea is to map each items to the sum up to that point.**

Comment: Yeah. But something is missing in my implementation.

Comment: `acc[inx-1]` won't work for the first iteration.

Comment: I'd do `numbers.map(((acc) => (v) => acc += v)(0))`

Comment: In your `.map` use `array[inx - 1]` and `array[inx]` (or `div`)

Answer (score 2):

using arrow function and map:

```
const res = numbers.map((accumulator => num => accumulator += num)(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation uses `inx`, but this is an index into the original array, so it doesn't make sense to use it in the accumulated array.

Instead, you can use the fact that the last element of the accumulated array is a running total:

```
numbers.reduce((acc, cur, inx) => [...acc, acc[acc.length-1] ? cur +acc[acc.length-1]: cur ], []);
```

or

```
numbers.reduce((acc, cur, inx) => [...acc, cur + acc[acc.length-1] ?? 0 ], []);
```

Comment: `cur + (acc[acc.length - 1] ?? 0)` would be slightly easier IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array.reduce() method for this purpose.

Answer (score -2):

```
numbers.reduce((acc, v, idx) => {
  if (acc[idx - 1]) {
    const value = v + acc[idx - 1];
    return [...acc, value];
  }
  return [...acc, v];
}, []);
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code-snippet. For example the JavaScript ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...` used or your lambda inside `reduce`.